# List index out of range - Index Error Python

Tags: python, loops

I am writing a function that will iterate through a list of text items -  parse each item, and append the parsed items back into a list. 
The code is as below:

```
clean_list = []

def to_words( list ):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(list):
        doc = list[i]
        # 1. Remove HTML
        doc_text = BeautifulSoup(doc).get_text() 
        # 2. Remove non-letters (not sure if this is advisable for all documents)       
        letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", doc_text) 
        # 3. Convert to lower case, split into individual words
        words = letters_only.lower().split()                                               
        # 4. Remove stop words
        stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
        meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]   
        # 5. Join the words back into one string separated by space, and return the result.
        clean_doc = ( " ".join( meaningful_words ))   
        i = i+1
        clean_list.append(clean_doc)
```

But when I pass the list into this function, `to_words(list)`, I get this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

I tried experimenting without technically defining the `to_words` function i.e. avoiding the loop, manually changing i as 0,1,2 etc, and following through the steps of the function; this works fine.

Why am I facing this error when I use the function (and loop)?

Comment: Can you give full traceback here ?

Comment: a list of length 5 has indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. - your `while i <= len(list)` gives `i` the values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Change it to `while i < len(list)`

Comment: Also don't use the variable name `list`, as this causes confusion with the `list` object type.

Comment: You could use `for doc in list` rather than incrementing `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`while i <= len(list)` to `while i < len(list)`

List indexing start from `0` so, `i <= len(list)` will satisfy the index as equal to `len(list)` so that's will make an index error.

1 . Better use for rather than using file loop, list support iterating through the `list`. Like

```
for elem in list_:
    # Do your operation here
```

2 . Don't use `list` as a variable name.